# Get position of tap using quo.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, console, touch

I'm trying to determine the position of a touch tap event using javascript.
The [quo.js](http://quojs.tapquo.com/) plugin I'm using helps recognise the touch events.

I thought this would work:

```
$('#quoTiles').tap(function(e){
  alert( e.pageX );
});
```

But it returns undefined. How do I get the coordinates of this tapped event?

Also, it would be useful if I could find out how to see all the possible parameters of the event such as pageX, pageY, iniTouch, currentTouch etc. I can't see them listed in firebug when I inspect the event.

Been trying to work this out for hours. Please please help me!

Comment: Have you resolved this in the meantime?

Answer (score 0):

**Getting coordinates**

`tap` does not expose the coordinates. You could use `touch` with `e.originalEvent.pageX` and `e.originalEvent.pageY` but in my tests on QuoJS 2.3.1 I had issues with `touch` not firing on touch devices (crazy, eh?).

With quo.js from the [current master branch](https://github.com/soyjavi/QuoJS) you could use `e.quoData.x` and `e.quoData.y` on the `tap` event. Downside: You have to build a release from the coffescript sources yourself.

**Debugging**

Concerning inspection of the event data passed to your handlers you can do

```
$$('selector').on('tap', function(e){
    console.log(e);
});
```

In the Firefox console you then get something like this:
Every tap event you trigger will give you a new line in the log. Clicking on a log line gives you a sidebar containing the browsable event object structure.

[image: Firefox debug console output for snippet above]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm still a little confused as to what the solution is. As you say, `e.originalEvent.pageX` seems to have issues working on touch devices and `e.quoData.x` is appearing undefined. I am trying to now get the center coordinates of a pinch event and feel no closer to knowing what code to use to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: Hey, as I wrote in my answer the e.qouData object gets filled only for the most recent version, that you won't find ready made as download. You will have to clone their repository, install the npm dependencies and run grunt to build it from scratch.

Comment: You can see a working example of the `tap` event passing `e.quoData` here: http://boomaco.canis.uberspace.de/demos/quojs/. If you need help with compiling just drop a note here.

Comment: Were you able to resolve your issue in the meantime?